# Find code that assigns onclick event to node

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a webpage that I didn't write.  There's a button which runs a JavaScript command when I click on it, but I can't figure out where the JavaScript code is that contains the .onClick or .click command which assigned that function to the click event.  Here is the code for the button:

```
<li><a href="#top" class="page-link btn-custom btn-sign-up-bottom"></a></li>
```

I know that I can use the Chrome dev tools and look under the elements tab->Event Listeners->click to show what function runs when I click it, but I want to find the line of code where the listener is set up.  It's tricky because the listener could have been assigned using any of the three classes that the button is part of, or it could be that all links were assigned this onClick.  I suspect I'll have to do this a lot, so I hope there's an efficient solution.

Comment: I think it's easier to find that event directly into the source code (i assume you can download the webpage source code)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can attach an onclick handler using chrome console like this and call debugger

```
$('.btn-sign-up-bottom').click(function(){
   debugger;
});
```

Javascript execution will break and then you can keep hitting F10 or F11 to step .. and see how it goes .. maybe you will step to the original event handler function !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to find the line, but with the following code you can find which function has added the event.

First add an id to the element, such as `myid`

Add this script just after the element:

```
var el=document.getElementById('myid');
el.oldAddEvent=el.addEventListener;
el.addEventListener=function f(a,b,c){
    if(a=='click'){
        alert((f.caller?f.caller+"\n\n":"Window ")+"has added a click event to\n\n"+b+"\n\nwith eventCapture="+(c?true:false));
    }
    el.oldAddEvent(a,b,c);
}
```

Then, if there's a script like this...

```
<script>
el.addEventListener('click',f,false);
</script>
```

...it will alert

```
Window has added a click event to

function f() {
    alert("click");
}

with eventCapture=false
```

And with this...

```
function g(){
el.addEventListener('click',f,false);
}
g();
```

...it will alert

```
function g() {
    el.addEventListener("click", f, false);
}

has added a click event to

function f() {
    alert("click");
}

with eventCapture=false
```